# For loop loop from startDate's day

Tags: javascript

```
for(let i=0;i<=range;i++){
  console.log(`${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${i}`);
}
```

my range value would be 5 if and I'm able to see the result from 2017-2-1 till 2017-2-6. But how to print from 2017-2-12 to 2017-2-17? I have 3 variables: startDate, endDate and range. I kinda messup this for loop part.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(let i=startdate;i<=startdate+range;i++){
  console.log(`${d.getFullYear()}-${d.getMonth()}-${i}`);
}
```

so for 12 to 17 you would set

```
var startdate = 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to modify the actual date object. Dates can get screwy when you have roll-over between months.

```js
const msInDay = 8.64e7,
      pad = (s, p) => (p + s).substr(-p.length),
      pad2 = s => pad(s, '00'),
      formatDate = d => `${d.getFullYear()}-${pad2(d.getMonth()+1)}-${pad2(d.getDate())}`;

var date = new Date(2017, 1, 12),
    days = 5;

let startTime = date.getTime(),
    endTime = startTime + (msInDay * days)

for (let time = startTime; time <= endTime; time += msInDay) {
  date.setTime(time);
  console.log(formatDate(date));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: why you even need to startTime? I just need the day. The day is from the value of a calendar, user will choose the date.

Comment: @GialaJefferson Try starting on the 28th for example and counting up 5 days. Your day method will not roll over into the next month.

Comment: It doesn't matter, user can click 'next month' on the calendar.